# Getting values from one array using the maximum value indices of another array

Tags: numpy

```
a = np.array([[11,12,39,14], [15,16,29,18]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]])
```

The expected result is[5,6,**3**,8]

I tried but could not solve.

```
result = b[range(len(a)), a.argmax(0)]
print (result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, you sliced in the incorrect order:

```
result = b[a.argmax(0), range(a.shape[1])]
```

Output: `array([5, 6, 3, 8])`